# Did Jessica Rabbit have sex with Valiant in his office?

Tags: who-framed-roger-rabbit

The dialog when Jessica Rabbit visits Valiant in his office in *Who Framed Roger Rabbit?* goes something like this:

> Mr Valiant Mr Valiant. You've got the wrong idea about me Mr Valiant.
>
> I am a pawn in this just like Roger. Can you help me find him? Just name your price and I'll pay it!
>
> No No I love my husband you got me all wrong. You don't how hard it is being a woman looking the way I do. I am not bad just drawn that way.
>
> I didn't want to have anything to do with it but he said if I didn't pose for that patty-cake pictures, Roger will never work in this town again. I couldn't let that happen I'll do anything for my husband Mr Valiant anything. (She dramatically moves closer to Eddie, with her bursting bosoms touching his chest ready to embrace him)

Does that mean that Jessica Rabbit had sex with Valiant in his office?

[image: Picture of Jessica Rabbit]

Comment: You get that the cartoons characters are somewhat innocent right?  Hence the 'scandal' of playing patty-cake?  I'm not sure whether this is enough for an answer - we certainly don't know definitively whether this happened or not, but it doesn't seem to be in keeping with the Roger Rabbit universe that they even could.

Comment: @iandotkelly The photos shown to Roger in the film clearly show her literally playing patty-cake. Seems like it'd be enough info. :D https://i.imgur.com/SsmYvHz.gif

Comment: @Catija That would probably make for an answer (together with some elaborations on the obvious and cartoonesque euphemism).

Comment: Actually, looks like the question is not about the patty-cake incident, but later when she is with Eddie Valiant in his own office.

Comment: @colmde ... that's what I took it to be too, that's where the quote and the picture is from - but I'm using the patty-cake incident to illustrate how innocent the toons are.

Comment: Did you not watch the movie? They clearly did not have sex.

Answer (score 9):

The story opens with Valiant being hired by R.K. Maroon to follow Jessica and uncover any evidence that she is romantically involved with Marvin Acme.

Valiant discovers and photographs them playing 'patty-cake'

[image: Marvin Acme and Jessica Rabbit playing patty-cake]

This is the 'scandalous' evidence of their affair, and when presented with the sequence of photographs Roger is distraught.  This is funny exactly because Roger is acting like she's been caught having a sexual affair.

In the Roger Rabbit universe, the rules of old children's cartoons apply.  In these cartoons you can have extreme violence with no blood or apparent long term damage and there is no sex. Toons pretty much can't die, even if a piano or a safe is dropped on them, and the most salacious interaction is a kiss, usually for comedic rather than romantic effect - think Pepe le Pew.

I think this shows that it is unlikely or even impossible that Jessica and Valiant could have sex.  Yes, she's a caricature of a sexy woman but it seems like the cartoon conventions that apply to the 'toons' they temperamentally just can't or don't have sex.

Comment: Dolores did jape at Eddie Valiant with a question "Working on your watercolors?" Implying the interchange of fluids between people and toons *might* be possible

Comment: @m1gp0z ... indeed but hard to tell - Jessica is obviously drawn to resemble a sexy woman, and Dolores is laughing at Eddie's discomfort.